# Wagtail custom permissions

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a wagtail site. I have certain pages that I only want certain users to be able to access. I have used the standard django permissions setup to do this:

models.py

```
class Case(TimeStampedModel):
    
    case_userdefined_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=17, null=False, blank=False, unique=True, default='default'
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(), blank=False, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    
    class Meta:
        permissions = (("can_access_case", "Can Access case"),)
```

views.py

```
class CreateCaseView(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = 'Case.can_access_case'
    print('test2')
    template_name = 'cases/create_case.html'
    form_class = CaseForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('patients')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = CaseForm()
        context['form'] = form
        return context
```

wagtail_hooks.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from wagtail import hooks


@hooks.register('register_permissions')
def view_restricted_page():
    return Permission.objects.filter(codename="can_access_case")
```

Then in the wagtail admin I have created a group 'case_access' and ticked the custom permissions to allow access. I have then made various users members of this group.

However  these users still get a '403 forbidden' screen, it is only superusers that can access the relevant pages.

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`permission_required = 'Case.can_access_case'` is incorrect. As per [the docs for the `permission_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator), the permission name consists of the app label (not the model name) followed by the permission name. So, if your Case model was part of the `cases` app, this would be `permission_required = 'cases.can_access_case'`.

Comment: Many thanks @gasman, I have changes so that the app label is there instead. I still get the same error however?

Comment: What is the URL that is giving 'forbidden'? I can't really tell where you have integrated your CreateCaseView

Comment: thanks - my other error was related to urls!